# Creating a simple "smooth scroll" (with javascript vanilla)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make a simple "smoothscroll" function using location.href that triggers on the mousewheel. The main problem is that the EventListener(wheel..) gets a bunch of inputs over the span of ca. 0,9 seconds which keeps triggering the function. "I only want the function to run once".

In the code below I have tried to remove the eventlistener as soon as the function runs, which actually kinda work, the problem is that I want it to be added again, hence the timed function at the bottom. This also kinda work but I dont want to wait a full second to be able to scroll and if I set it to anything lover the function will run multiple times.
I've also tried doing it with conditions "the commented out true or false variables" which works perfectly aslong as you are only scrolling up and down but you cant scroll twice or down twice.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', scrolltest, true);
function scrolltest(event) {
    window.removeEventListener('wheel', scrolltest, true);
    i = event.deltaY;
    console.log(i);

    if (webstate == 0) {
        if (i < 0 && !upexecuted) {
            // upexecuted = true;
            location.href = "#forside";
            // downexecuted = false;
        } else if (i > 0 && !downexecuted) {
            // downexecuted = true;
            location.href = "#underside";
            // upexecuted = false;
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function(){ window.addEventListener('wheel', scrolltest, true); }, 1000);
}
```

I had hoped there was a way to stop the wheel from constantly produce inputs over atleast 0.9 seconds.

"note: don't know if it can help in some way but when the browser is not clicked (the active window) the wheel will registre only one value a nice 100 for down and -100 for up"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a different approach**
okey after fiddeling with this for just about 2 days i got fustrated and started over. no matter what i did the browsers integrated "glide-scroll" was messing up the event trigger. anyway i decided to animate the scrolling myself and honestly it works better than i had imagined: here is my code if anyone want to do this:

```
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    var p1 = document.getElementById('page1');
    var p2 = document.getElementById('page2');
    var p3 = document.getElementById('page3');
    var p4 = document.getElementById('page4');
    var p5 = document.getElementById('page5');
    var whatpage = 1;
    var snap = 50;
    var i = 0;

// this part is really just to read what "page" you are on if you update the site. if you add more pages you should remember to add it here too.
window.onload = setcurrentpage;
function setcurrentpage() {
    if (window.pageYOffset == p1.offsetTop) {
        whatpage = 1;
    } else if (window.pageYOffset == p2.offsetTop) {
        whatpage = 2;
    } else if (window.pageYOffset == p3.offsetTop) {
        whatpage = 3;
    } else if (window.pageYOffset == p4.offsetTop) {
        whatpage = 4;
    } else if (window.pageYOffset == p5.offsetTop) {
        whatpage = 5;
    }
}

// this code is designet to automaticly work with any "id" you have aslong as you give it a variable called p"number" fx p10 as seen above.
function smoothscroll() {
    var whatpagenext = whatpage+1;
    var whatpageprev = whatpage-1;
    var currentpage = window['p'+whatpage];
    var nextpage = window['p'+whatpagenext];
    var prevpage = window['p'+whatpageprev];
    console.log(currentpage);
    if (window.pageYOffset > currentpage.offsetTop + snap && window.pageYOffset < nextpage.offsetTop - snap){
        body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
        i++
        window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset+i);
            if (window.pageYOffset <= nextpage.offsetTop + snap && window.pageYOffset >= nextpage.offsetTop - snap) {
                i=0;
                window.scrollTo(0, nextpage.offsetTop);
                whatpage += 1;
                body.style.overflowY = "initial";
            }
    } else if (window.pageYOffset < currentpage.offsetTop - snap && window.pageYOffset > prevpage.offsetTop + snap){
            body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
            i--
            window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset+i);
                if (window.pageYOffset >= prevpage.offsetTop - snap && window.pageYOffset <= prevpage.offsetTop + snap) {
                    i=0;
                    window.scrollTo(0, prevpage.offsetTop);
                    whatpage -= 1;
                    body.style.overflowY = "initial";
                }
        }
}
```

to remove the scrollbar completely just add this to your stylesheet:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  
    background: transparent;  
}
```

Comment: i see that the damn integrated "glide-scroll" is still messing it up in smaller window sizes. adding a timer to body.style.overflowY = "initial"; which allows scrolling fixes the problem fx. setTimeout(function(){ body.style.overflowY = "initial"; }, 500);. the higher you set the delay the more failproof it will be however the longer you will have to wait to be able to scroll. tested 500 miliseconds and it seem to work on very small window sizes.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called "debouncing" or "throttling". (Those aren't exactly the same thing, but you can look up the difference in case it's going to matter to you.) Functions for this are built into libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce), but if using a library like that is too non-vanilla for what you have in mind, you can always define your own debounce function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/debouncing-in-javascript/

You might also want to look into [`requestanimationframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: i tried adding a debounce function but i am kinda left with the same problem. instead of waiting to to be able to input i now am waiting for the function to execute and as before if i set the the delay too high the function will trigger multiple times.